# Using new keyword without defining variable in java

Tags: java, object, instantiation

The following code is used to create an object of a class within a variable:

```
ClassName obj = new ClassName();
```

But what if we do not create any variable and just type the following?

```
new ClassName();
```

When I used it, there was no error. But what it actually does when no variable is created?

Comment: It _does_ create an object.

Comment: It creates an object.  Whether or not that object is then referenced by a variable is a different matter entirely.

Answer (score 1):

> To answer to your question I think is useful to see how objects are managed by JVM during execution.

All java **objects** reside in a JVM area called *heap* and **can** ( note that this is not mandatory ) be pointed by one or more variables.
The **variables** that hold references to objects reside on another area of JVM called *stack*.

Every time an instruction like `new SomeClass();` is executed a new object is allocated on that area. When the heap area becomes full, garbage is collected and during the garbage collection objects that are no longer pointed by a variable are cleared in order to free space on heap for new objects.

**What is the difference between your two instructions?**

[image]

1- `ClassName obj = new ClassName();`

It allocates a new object on heap that is pointed by the **obj** variable on stack.

2- `new ClassName();`

It just allocates a new object on heap with no variables on stack that point to it.

**When can be useful to use the second approach?**

According to this, using the second approach could be useful if you want just to allocate a new object on heap without using it through a variable for example to test memory management on your program. Actually the second approach is used when you want to create a "one-shot" object and use a method or a variable of it in the same instruction improving the garbage collector efficiency and avoiding unexpectedly get an OutOfMemoryError exception like:

- using once time an object variable:

```
System.out.println(new ClassName().x)
```

or

- executing once time an object method:

```
new ClassName().evaluateResult();
```

**NOTE:** In this specific case you probably could evaluate instead to make a **static method** on the class.

Another usage can be to put new elements on a collection as follow:

```
final List<ClassName> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
  objectList.add(new ClassName());
}
```

---

You can may ask: **What happens instead to objects that are pointed by
at least one variable like ones created with first approach?**

All references that are held in a variable are naturally dropped when the variable goes out of scope so they became eligible for garbage collection automatically ( according how their scope is managed on code ).

Answer (score 0):

Both methods create an object, but the second method has no name for it.

When you create an instance of the ClassName, the difference between your first method and second method is that for your first method, you can actually access variables and methods within the class.

For example,

```
ClassName obj = new ClassName();
System.out.println(obj.x);
```

Where ClassName

```
class ClassName {
    public static int x = 2;
}
```

The benefit of this approach is you can access the variables within the class. If you used the second approach, then the instance would have no name, so you wouldn't be able to access the variables.

Comment: Really with second approach you can also access variables and methods if you do it inline within object creation like for example doing `System.out.println(new ClassName().x)`

Comment: Sure, but you can only do it once. Imagine if you wanted to find 2 different values at 2 different parts of the code. Such as maybe you want to get x and do some math with it, and get another variable at the end. For demonstration, I used this as an example

Comment: Sure, if you need to use the created object in different points, within the object scope, you need to define a variable in order to reuse it and access variables and methods multiple times and so first approach is the correct one. 
But as you write `If you used the second approach ....  you wouldn't be able to access the variables.` this can confuse the OP because really it is possible as I indicated on my comment and this can be useful for example if you want to avoid to define an object variable that you would use once only at that point also improving the garbage collector efficiency

Comment: Yes. My bad, I was just using it as an example to simplify the approach.

Answer (score 0):

`new ClassName()` calls a special method called a constructor and, like any method, it returns a value<sup>1</sup>. The value that it returns is an instance of `ClassName`. You can choose to assign that value to a variable, or not, just as you can do with the return value of any method. So you simply need to decide whether you need to assign the returned value to a variable, or not. If you do, then you need the first statement, namely:

```java
ClassName obj = new ClassName();
```

And if you don't need to assign the returned value to a variable, then you can use:

```java
new ClassName();
```

<sup>1 - a method can return *void* which means it doesn't actually return a value</sup>